# How to stop refreshing stashed append across page loads?

Tags: stash

I'm trying a different approach to random ordering and pagination, as this approach seems doomed: ([Paginating a random ordered list of tag:related_entries](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41526/paginating-a-random-ordered-list-of-tagrelated-entries))

I'm setting the list of IDs in order and then trying to use them in a fixed_order parameter, which I believe will work with pagination:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="start"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries
        channel="things-to-do"
        disable="category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"
        status="open"
        dynamic="no"
        cache="no"
        orderby="random"
    }
        {exp:stash:append replace="no" name="viewed_ids" scope="user" save="yes"}{entry_id}|{/exp:stash:append}

    {/exp:tag:related_entries} 

{/exp:stash:parse}
```

And trying to retrieve like this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="entries" parse_tags="yes" process="end"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="channel_one"
        disable="category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"
        status="open"
        dynamic="no"
        cache="no"
        fixed_order="{stash:viewed_ids}"
        limit="3"
    }
        {stash:id}{entry_id}{/stash:id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}

    {/exp:channel:entries} 
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

But it's not working quite right, viewed_ids is getting refreshed every page load.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the {exp:channel:entries} sections that shows your results to an embed and then putting a [cache time for that embed file](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/optimization/caching.html#template-caching)

Comment: No good unfortunately